# Pass products detail via paypal

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm creating a simple paypal checkout where the customer can check out via PayPal. Below is the sample code i am using for paypal checkout.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="kids t-shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="200.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"  name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

As you can see, a simply form that passes product name and price which customer can see in their order summary.however how can i pass products details such as product size and color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the some more hidden value.check the below code.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="kids t-shirt">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="200.00">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size" />
<input type="hidden" value="your size value" name="os0">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="color" />
<input type="hidden" value="your color value" name="os1">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"  name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```